# How to create alias to template method

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

From this [link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1244) *(1056. Template aliases, member definitions, and the current instantiation)* I realised that, We can create alias in templates, for example we could do as below

```
template<typename T>
using Vec = std::vector<int>
```

How can I create alias for a template method, I tried below but it throws compilation error `error: missing template arguments before '.' token`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> struct A 
{
    float g(T x){return(x*0.01);}
};

template <class T> using B = A<T>;

int main() 
{
    B.g<int>(10);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how to create alias for template method, Please someone shed light on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have little misorder in your line, the correct one should be:

```
B<int>().g(10);
```

ie. You create a `B<int>` object and call the function `g` of it.

By compiling the code with clang it gives very precise error messages:

```
tmpl.cpp:13:5: error: use of class template 'B' requires template arguments
    B.g<int>(10);
    ^
tmpl.cpp:9:20: note: template is declared here
template <class T> using B = A<T>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
tmpl.cpp:13:6: error: cannot use dot operator on a type
    B.g<int>(10);
     ^
```